# Why larger UPS are more expensive than several smaller ones?

Tags: ups

I want to buy a UPS, but isn't clear to me why this [UPS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00I8RVZ9W) (2700W) is more expensive than three of [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FBK3QK), is almost double the price. I prefer the convenience of having only one UPS to secure all my equipment, but the costs are less if I choose the smaller ones.

Is there any real difference between the big one and the smaller ones?

Comment: The more expensive one does power conditioning, outputs a pure sine wave. It is geared toward a commercial market.

Comment: Popularity in the market can also drive down costs of smaller units.  If more people buy smaller units and don't need the larger ones then manufacturers can make the smaller ones in larger batches and drive the cost down. This has the side effect of making the larger ones proportionately more expensive and less popular, hence widening the gap.